# What physical size and density floppies are the intermediate-capacity options for the /F switch of the DOS/Windows/OS/2 FORMAT command meant for?

Tags: ms-dos, floppy-disk, windows, os2

In MS-DOS 5.0 and newer, PC-DOS 5.0 and newer, Windows 9x, Windows NT 3.1–2000, and OS/2 4.x, the FORMAT command (present in some form or another in literally every single version of Q/86-/MS-/PC-DOS, Windows, and OS/2 ever) offers the `/F` switch for choosing what capacity to format a floppy disk to.<sup>1</sup>

In DOS 5+ and Windows 9x, the description of the `/F` switch (brought up, along with much other information, by entering `format /?` at the command prompt) is as follows:

> /F:size          Specifies the size of the floppy disk to format (such as 160, 180, 320, 360, 720, 1.2, 1.44, 2.88).

The description of the Windows NT 3.1–4.0 `/F` switch is (apart from a slight change in wording and the addition of support for 20385 KiB floptical disks) almost identical:

> /F:size          Specifies the size of the floppy disk to format (160, 180, 320, 360, 720, 1.2, 1.44, 2.88, or 20.8).

Windows 2000’s `/F` switch has considerably greater functionality:

> /F:size          Specifies the size of the floppy disk to format (160, 180, 320, 360, 640, 720, 1.2, 1.23, 1.44, 2.88, or 20.8).

The OS/2 /F switch is the simplest of all:

> /F:xxxx          Specifies the size to which the diskette is to be formatted.  For example: 360, 720, 1.2, 1.44, 2.88.

For most of these options, even though the only thing specified is the (approximate) formatted capacity,<sup>3</sup> there is no ambiguity as to what size, density, and sideness of floppies they are for:

- 160: 160 KiB (40 tracks per side, 8 sectors per track) single-sided double-density (SSDD) 5.25″ floppy
- 180: 180 KiB (40 tps, 9 spt) SSDD 5.25″ floppy
- 720: 720 KiB (80 tps, 9 spt) double-sided double-density (DSDD) 3.5″ floppy
- 1.2: 1200 KiB (80 tps, 15 spt) double-sided high-density (DSHD) 5.25″ floppy
- 1.23: 1232 KiB (77 tps, 8 spt) DSDD 8″ floppy<sup>4</sup>
- 1.44: 1440 KiB (80 tps, 18 spt) DSHD 3.5″ floppy
- 2.88: 2880 KiB (80 tps, 36 spt) double-sided extended-density (DSED) 3.5″ floppy
- 20.8: 20385 KiB (755 tps, 27 spt) double-sided floptical disk

However, for the remaining three, there are multiple floppy formats with a capacity that fits:

- 320:

  - 320 KiB (40 tps, 8 spt) DSDD 5.25″ floppy, *or...*
  - 320 KiB (80 tps, 8 spt) single-sided quad-density (SSQD) 5.25″ floppy, *or...*
  - 320 KiB (80 tps, 8 spt) SSDD 3.5″ floppy
- 360:

  - 360 KiB (40 tps, 9 spt) DSDD 5.25″ floppy, *or...*
  - 360 KiB (80 tps, 9 spt) SSDD 3.5″ floppy
- 640:

  - 640 KiB (80 tps, 8 spt) double-sided quad-density (DSQD) 5.25″ floppy, *or...*
  - 640 KiB (80 tps, 8 spt) DSDD 3.5″ floppy

For each of these three `/F` options, which of the two (or *three*, in 320’s case) possible formats is the option intended to produce?  Does it change at all, depending on whether the drive holding the floppy disk to be formatted is a 5.25″ or a 3.5″ drive (distinguishing between DSDD, SSQD, and DSQD 5.25-inchers, on the one hand, and SSDD and DSDD 3.5-inchers, on the other), or maybe on whether the /1 switch (used to tell FORMAT to format only one side of the disk) is used (distinguishing, for 320 and 360,<sup>5</sup> between DSDD 5.25-inchers, on the one hand, and SSQD 5.25-inchers and SSDD 3.5-inchers, on the other)?

---

<sup>1</sup>: The `/F` switch is *technically* still present in every Windows NT version from Windows XP right up through Windows 10, but has been neutered, with only the “1.44” (1440-KiB DSHD 3.5″ floppy) option available.<sup>2</sup>

<sup>2</sup>: Floppies *can* still be formatted to other capacities on these systems, assuming that the floppy drive’s firmware supports non-1440-KiB-DSHD-3.5″ formats (most internal floppy drives do; most USB floppy drives don’t), but this requires the user to manually enter the number of tracks per side and the number of sectors per track (using the /T and /N switches, respectively), and the support present in earlier NT versions for formatting single-sided disks is, so far as I can tell, completely gone.

<sup>3</sup>: In contrast, the `/F` switch for *DR*-DOS’s FORMAT command explicity states what sizes of disks its various options correspond to; unfortunately, as DR-DOS is a completely independent development (though an essentially-completely-binary-compatible one) from Microsoft and IBM’s offerings, one can in no way assume that the list of floppy formats supported by DR-DOS is exactly the same as that supported by [MS-/PC]-DOS/Windows/OS/2.

<sup>4</sup>: The capacity of a DSDD 8″ floppy is 1232 KiB, rather than the 616 KiB one would expect from the per-disk sector count, because DD 8-inchers use 1024-byte sectors rather than the 512-byters standard on the smaller sizes of floppies.  (*Single*-density [SD] 8-inchers, which are not supported by any FORMAT version of which I am aware, use 128-byte sectors.)

<sup>5</sup>: It wouldn’t help for 640, as *both* of the two disk formats with 640-KiB capacity are double-sided.

Comment: @TomasBy: To properly format the disk, the OS has to feed the drive the track/sector/side arrangement for the correct disk geometry - which can differ between two disks of the same capacity (for instance, a 360-KiB 40/9 DSDD 5.25" floppy versus a 360-KiB 80/9 SSDD 3.5" floppy).

Comment: I think 20.8 MB might have also been the experimental triple-density disk standard that never caught on.

Comment: @fuz, I'm not sure if it was considered 'experimental' or not, but the 20Meg disk was called a "floptical" which had magnetic media but used optical head alignment. A floptical disk had 1250 tracks per inch, instead of the standard 1.44Meg's 135tpi. It could be considered a precursor to the Iomega Zip drive/disk system.

Comment: The 8" drives I used with a CP/M-80 system, used 512 bytes sectors.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In fact, you can use *any* of these formats (up to 1.44MB) on a 3.5" or 5.25" DSHD floppy disk.  For the 40-track formats, an 80-track drive would need to double-step; for the single-sided formats, only one head of a double-sided drive would be activated.  There are even extended formats which fit, say, 1.6MB in by using a still-higher number of sectors per track.

Filling in the details, 320K and 360K are just double-sided versions of the 40-track, single-sided 160K and 180K formats.  Then 640K would be an 8-sector variant of the 9-sector 720K format, probably intended for 5.25" DSDD drives on which 8-sector formats were more commonly used.  This also makes it a logical 80-track upgrade from the 320K format.

Comment: Particularly for 3.5" drives in the early '80s, single-sided 80 tracks/side drives were not uncommon. (The Mac initially used these, for example.) The normal formatting of these would also be 320K/360K using PC formatting standards, if PCs had ever used them. (I am guessing they did not.)

Comment: @cjs the ever-mysterious (online info about it is essentially zero) Epson QX-11 (aka “Abacus”) sold in Latin America in the 80s used 3½" floppies with 640KB capacity. Few PC-compatible machines could read those disks and I‘m sure it was due to an unusual usage of tracks (Norton’s DiskEdit could always see all of track 0, but fail beyond). I always assumed it was double-sided but skipping every other track. Now you make me wonder if it was a single-sided drive instead. Do you have links with info on those?

Comment: @EuroMicelli I have no particular information on those, but 640 KB would be exactly what you'd expecte for a double-sided 80 track/side 8×512 byte sector format, which was quite standard (though perhaps not in the PC world) for both 5.25" and 3.5" diskettes. (The controller used both identically.) A single-sided double-density disk would hold only half that much, so it definitely wasn't that. If you get hold of any technical docs, I will be happy to look them over.

Comment: @cjs, Sorry. I meant **360KB**. It was presented to DOS as a conventional 40-track 9-sector/track Double-Sided drive. The obvious way to implement that is by using half of the tracks of the disk, but it’s unclear “which” half other than “track 0 is the same” (see DISKEDIT comment). I would do anything for any technical info on the machine, but it’s been impossible to find any. I would avidly study anything I could find. Thanks for the offer anyway.

Comment: @EuroMicelli Or another likely way to implement it, especially given the time period (1984 or '85?) is as an _actual_ conventional double-sided 40-track/side 9×512-byte/sector drive, using all of the tracks of each disk. These did exist (the Fujitsu FM77 series [used them](http://ja1wby.art.coocan.jp/hamg/7-fm7-fdd/2-yd-625.html) from 1984 through 1986) though they were rare in the PC-compatible world. [Here's a datasheet](https://archive.org/details/bitsavers_yeDataFDK5tionsJan85_1176370/mode/1up).

Comment: We discovered that downformatting a 1.44MB floppy to 720K didn't work when we put it into a 720K drive. Didn't think at the time to put it into the 720K drive computer and issue a format command from there at the time but rather tracked down an actual 720K floppy to shuffle data with.

Answer (score 12):

[KB entry Q75131](https://jeffpar.github.io/kbarchive/kb/075/Q75131/) provides the following answer for MS-DOS `FORMAT`:

- 320: 320-KiB (40 tps, 8 spt) DSDD 5.25” floppy
- 360: 360-KiB (40 tps, 9 spt) DSDD 5.25” floppy

I don’t know about the Windows-only 640 format.